# Missing Template and Controller Issues in Rails Project (rating)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rating, railscasts, polymorphism

I am stuck on a problem and i would love a hand! I got the polymorphic association from railscast #154

So far I have gotten the comment model working splendidly. However I want to create a rating model as well that I can then add js to make pretty.

Looked at every other tutorial/stackoverflows I could find. None of them show how to work with multiple polymorphic associations in a controller.

I tried to duplicate the code for the article_controller but I am not sure how to do that for both models. So far my attempts have been unsuccessful. The partial form has the proper name, it is _ratings.html.erb

**My Error:**

```
Missing partial ratings/ratings with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/code/jimbo/bigdog/app/views"
  * "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@lulla-core/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views"
  * "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@lulla-core/gems/devise-3.1.1/app/views"
```

**My Models:**

```
 class Rating
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes

  field :value, type: Integer, default: "0"

  belongs_to :rateable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**My Controllers:**

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :load_rateable

  def index
    @ratings = @rateable.rating
  end

  def show
    @rating = @rateable.ratings.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
    end
  end

  def new
    @rating = @rateable.rating.new
  end

  def create
    @rating = @rateable.rating.new(params[:rating])
    if @rating.save
      redirect_to @rateable, notice: "Rating created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def load_rateable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
    @rateable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end

  # def load_commentable
  #   klass = [Article, Photo, Event].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"] }
  #   @rateable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
  # end
end
```

**Article Controller**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json

  def index
    @articles = Article.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @articles }
    end
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @article
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @article }
    end
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  # GET /articles/new.json
  def new
    @article = Article.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @article }
    end
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @article, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /articles/1
  # PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

**My View:**

show.html (article)

```
<%= render "comments/comments" %>
<%= render "comments/form" %>

<%= render "ratings/ratings" %>
<%= render "ratings/form" %>
```

**Routes:**

```
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
    resources :ratings  
  end
```

Comment: if comments/comments works fine, then ratings/ratings should also work, double check if there is anything missed in views filename or folder name. and yes add full error info after "searched in" too.

Comment: Would I just add it the same to application controller in the same manner? I am a bit confused about that. I will check over my code again.

`def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @article
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @article }
    end
  end `

Comment: fixed, I am dumb lol! Thanks

Comment: ohh gud... is there was a typo?

Comment: I forgot to pluralize the view folder title.

Comment: yes thats why I said .. "double check folder name or filename".

Comment: I know. I am going through it again corrected everything but still getting an error.
`undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`

For `<div id="ratings">
<% @ratings.each do |rating| %>
  <div class="rating">
    <%= simple_format rating.content %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>`

I am assuming a typo unless it is an error in the article controller def show

Comment: bcoz u dont have anything in @ratings.

Comment: add something like @ratings = 'your query' in show action of articles controller.

Comment: kk, was thinking something like...

` @rateable = @article
    @ratings = @rateable.ratings
    @ratings = Rating.new `
But I am going to research more as I am new. Cheers!

Comment: hmm what u assign to @ratings is depends on ur project's need.